# Build errors with Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

After a check in from Visual Studio 2013 I am getting the following 2 build errors:

C:\a\src\project.nuget\nuget.targets (58): The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config' because it is being used by another process.

C:\a\src\project.nuget\nuget.targets (58): The command ""C:\a\src\project.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\a\src\project\WebWorkerRole\packages.config" -source "" -o "C:\a\src\project\packages"" exited with code 1.

Comment: Looks like a big problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb84146d-772c-446f-a563-96fcfa759ecb/tfs-online-build-error-in-nugettargets?forum=TFService&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enabled NuGet Package Restore in your solution? This adds nuget.exe and nuget.config into your solution and build can use it locally. To enable NuGet Package Restore right click on the Solution node in Solution Explorer and select Enable NuGet Package Restore (see NuGet documentation).